# How to keep a contentScript working when its jetpack panel changes location

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In a Firefox extension using [jetpack](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/), I have a [panel](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/1.0b5/docs/packages/addon-kit/docs/panel.html) with a [contentScript](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/1.0b5/docs/dev-guide/addon-development/web-content.html) attached. The panel is set to initially display an URL. If the panel changes its location (through a click on a link or a `document.location=`), I can't emit messages to the contentScript anymore (it raises an ERR_DESTROYED, "The page has been destroyed and can no longer be used.").

Is there a way to keep my contentScript working (or at least reload it) when the location changes? Or should I avoid changing location totally an only manipulate the original panel content?

Here's a minimal script showing the behavior:

```
exports.main = function (options, callbacks) {
  panel = require("panel").Panel({
    contentURL: "http://stackoverflow.com/",
    contentScript: 'self.port.on("foo", function() { console.log("foo received"); });'
  });

  widget = require("widget").Widget({
    id: "test-panel",
    label: "test panel",
    contentURL: "http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico",
    panel: panel
  });

  panel.on("show", function() {
    panel.port.emit("foo");
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an [answer from Myk Melez](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla-labs-jetpack/J13CJtuwM7w/qpZEcI0HNtcJ) on the [Jetpack google group](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla-labs-jetpack):

> For now, you should avoid changing the
>   panel's location and only manipulate
>   the original panel content, since
>   there isn't a way to keep the content
>   scripts working. But we should
>   probably make the panel's content
>   scripts get reloaded when its location
>   changes.

Or, as [lcamacho said](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla-labs-jetpack/J13CJtuwM7w/ZU--h3ty_gsJ), I can use an iframe inside the panel.